Can't load pivot table when read excel
I am using ExcelJS to read Excel file, my template have some pivot table inside, and when I'm handling data and pushing raw data in another sheet (I'm not doing anything in that sheet contains the pivot table), my pivot table is lost when saved as a new file.
can you guy tell me how to load the pivot table and save it without losing the pivot table
